# size of panel in panel using wxPython incorrect

Tags: python, wxpython, size, panel, wxwidgets

I have a problem with wxPython. I have a frame and in that frame, I have a panel. In that panel, I want another panel of fixed size (100x100). My code is below:

```
import wx

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)
        self.SetSize((100, 100))


class ExampleFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetMinSize((-1, -1))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        self.filesize = TestPanel(self.panel, -1)

        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hSizer.Add(self.filesize, 0, wx.CENTER)

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.Add(hSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vSizer)


app = wx.App(False)
frame = ExampleFrame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When I run the program, my `TestPanel` widget is only 1x1 pixels. However, when I print the size using the `GetSize` method, it says that the size is 100x100. Why does it display as a 1x1 red block in this case?

I'm using wxPython 3.0.2.0 on OS X.

Comment: i am not sure, what's your problem. When i run the code on ubuntu 15.10 and python-wxgtk2.8  and python 2.7.8, the code works just fine

Comment: That's strange since if I run this code, it displays as 1x1 block, not 100x100. I guess it is OS X related...

Comment: That could be a reason. Maybe you could try using the SizeHints function instead of setMinSize for your white panel

Comment: It is not OS X related. I get the same issue on Win 7.

Comment: Try changing line 7 from `self.SetSize((100, 100))` to `self.SetMinSize((100, 100))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `SetSize()` doesn't work, but you can just pass the size to the constructor. That worked for me on Windows 7 with wxPython 3.0.2 where calling `SetSize` did not.

```
import wx

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, size=(100, 100), *args)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.Layout()


class ExampleFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetMinSize((-1, -1))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)

        self.filesize = TestPanel(self.panel, -1)

        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hSizer.Add(self.filesize, 0, wx.CENTER)

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.Add(hSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vSizer)

import wx.lib.inspection
app = wx.App(False)
frame = ExampleFrame(None)
frame.Show()
wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working for me. I'm still wondering why `SetSize` does not work however...

Comment: Me too. You might want to ask on the wxPython Google group. They might be able to shed some light on this.